# Axios.post returns send null even though backend is working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, .net, api, axios

I am making an application where a user can make an Order for Kebab.

However when i'm using Axios.post some of the values always return null (Kebab and Drink).

When i'm using postman it all works as expected though, so it must be something with the frontend, I reckon.

This is my orderForm component:

```
export const OrderForm = (props: OrderFormProps) => {

    const [kebabChoice, setKebabChoice] = useState<KebabDto[]>();
    const [drinkChoice, setDrinkChoice] = useState<DrinkDto[]>();
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        axios.get(`https://localhost:7117/api/Kebab`)
        .then((response: AxiosResponse<KebabDto[]>) =>{
            setKebabChoice(response.data);

        })
    },[])
    useEffect(()=>{
        axios.get(`https://localhost:7117/api/Drink`)
        .then((response: AxiosResponse<DrinkDto[]>) =>{
            setDrinkChoice(response.data);

        })
    },[])

    return(
        <Formik
            initialValues = {props.model}
            onSubmit = {props.onSubmit}
            validationSchema = {Yup.object({
                firstName: Yup.string().required('This field is required').firstLetterUppercase()
            })}
        >
            {(formikProps) =>(
                <Form>
                    
                <TextField displayName="Firstname" field="firstName" type="text"/>
                <TextField displayName="Lastname" field="lastName" type="text" />
                <TextField displayName="Employee number" field="empNr" type="number" />
                
                <SelectField displayName="Kebab" field="typeOfKebab"  optionLabel="Välj kebab">
                        <>
                            {kebabChoice?.map(kebabs => 
                                <option key={kebabs.id} value={kebabs.name}>{kebabs.name}</option>)}
                        </>  
                </SelectField>
                <SelectField displayName="drink" field="typeOfDrink"  optionLabel="Välj Dricka">
                        <>
                            {drinkChoice?.map(drinks => 
                                <option key={drinks.id} value={drinks.typeOfDrink}>{drinks.typeOfDrink}</option>)}
                        </>  
                </SelectField>

                <Button className="btn btn-primary" disabled={formikProps.isSubmitting} type="submit">Save Changes</Button>
                <Link className="btn btn-secondary mt-2" to="/drinks">Cancel</Link>
                </Form>
            )}
        </Formik>
    )
}

interface OrderFormProps{
    model: OrderDto;
    onSubmit(values: OrderDto, actions: FormikHelpers<OrderDto>) : void;
}
```

Here i am also fetching the different kinds of kebabs and drinks that the user can choose from.

Here is the component where I'm trying to create the order:

```
export const CreateOrder = () => {

    const history = useHistory()

    const  CreateNewOrder = async (order: OrderDto) =>{
        try {
            await axios.post('https://localhost:7117/api/Order', order);
            console.log(order)
            history.push("/orders");
    
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }

    return(


        <>
            <h3>Create Order</h3>

            <OrderForm model={{firstName: '', lastName: '', empNr: 0}}
                onSubmit={values => 
                    CreateNewOrder(values)
                    // console.log(values)
                }
            />

        </>
    )
}
```

It takes one argument where the order is a type of OrderDto:

```
export interface OrderDto{
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    empNr?: number;
    kebab?: KebabDto;
    drink?:DrinkDto;
}
```

So when im creating a pizza, i get the values in my backend from firstName, lastName and empNr. Though Kebab and Drink is always null no matter what I do, except if im using Postman.

Postman body:

```
{
  "firstName": "Marcus",
  "lastName": "Rosberg",
  "empNr": 1111,
  "kebab": {
    "name": "Kebabrulle"
  },
  "drink": {
    "typeOfDrink": "Fanta"
  }
}
```

.net backend:

```
EndPoint:

[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> PostOrder([FromBody] OrderCreationDto orderCreation)
        {

            
            var order = mapper.Map<Order>(orderCreation);

            context.Orders.Add(order);
            //await context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return NoContent();
        }

OrderCreationDto:
 public class OrderCreationDto
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int EmpNr { get; set; }
        public KebabCreationDto Kebab { get; set; }
        public DrinkCreationDto Drink { get; set; }
    }

KebabCreationDto:

 public class KebabCreationDto
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

DrinkCreationDto:

 public class DrinkCreationDto
    {
        public string TypeOfDrink { get; set; }

    }
```

This is the code im currently using for my orders. I made a relationship between Order => kebab and Order => Drink where  and order is supposed to have one Drink and one kebab.

In my form in react im fetching Kebab and Drinks and use these in an option so that i can use whats already in the database and put it in my order. Atleast thats how it is supposed to work.

Comment: Have you set the kebab and the drink in the order dto?
Does it log correctly in the javascript? And if it is good in react console.log then you have a problem in your backend

Comment: If i console.log the values from my form i get the expected data

Comment: So the problem is then in the backend? I also mean this log "console.log(order)" in "CreateNewOrder "

Comment: I dont think the problem is in the backend. Like i said it works fine from postman

Answer (score 0):

Your drink and kebab fields are labeled `typeOfDrink` and `typeOfKebab` I cant see that you do any processing of these values and the api expects. `kebab` and `drink` fields.

If you only need to pass the drink/kebab type to the api and the api can resolve the drink/kebab that should be fine and you should just update the api and the interface to only take those fields. However if you need more meta data from Drink-/KebabDto you will need to accommodate that in the frontend. Either by making sure the that data is set in the form or resolve it from the type before passing it to the backend.

EDIT:

With the updated answer you can see that the for will not give you the same object as you pass with postman.

You will have to change the filed to accommodate the type you expect in the api: field="typeOfKebab" => field="kebab.name" and field="typeOfDrink" => field="drink.typeOfDrink"

```
<SelectField displayName="Kebab" field="kebab.name"  optionLabel="Välj kebab">
<SelectField displayName="drink" field="drink.typeOfDrink"  optionLabel="Välj Dricka">
```

However since you only use one field in both KebabDto and DrinkDto, why not just change OrderDto to

```
export interface OrderDto{
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    empNr?: number;
    kebab?: string;
    drink?: string;
}
```

Comment: If im changing the fields i get a 400 badrequest error

Comment: Yeah probably since the api expects Drink-/KebabDto not just the type that you get from the form. You should try to strive to send the least amount of fields to the api, if you only need the type of a drink or kebab just send that. I have update my answer.

Comment: Well, i tried to change it up so that drink and kebab is just a simple string, both in frontend and backend, still facing the same problem

Comment: Have you updated the code in the question to factor in your changes? 
Could you share the body you use when you post from postman, and could you share the backend code.

Comment: I updated my Post to show the backend code and postman body. It seems to me that either the form doesnt send the Kebabs and Drinks as expected, or the backend does not know how to handle these types for some reason.

Comment: Update my answer, hope it helps